# what does 1x 3x etc mean in karma code coverage report in Angular Unit testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, istanbul, karma-coverage

I am new to Unit Testing in Angular. I got the `karma` setup with code coverage along with `angular-cli` . I have run the command ng-test and opened code coverage report. I saw `1x` ,`3x` etc along with my code line numbers in that coverage report. Please find the my coverage report image.

[image]

Here is my test case code `app.component.spec.ts`

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */

import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    });
  });

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it(`should have as title 'app works!'`, async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('app works!');
  }));

  it('should render title in a h1 tag', async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('app works!');
  }));
});
```

I didn't understand what is the importance of that `1x,2x,3x` etc in my code report. Please help me in knowing the importance of that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It represents the amount of times that line has been executed.

According to your code lets take a look at your `title` field:

It first gets executed: `expect(app).toBeTruthy();`

Second: `expect(app.title).toEqual('app works!');`

Third:    `expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('app works!');`

So that's why it says 3x at the left of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @echonax. If there is any more info which you forgot to tell , please share me or you can elaborate it in your answer. Thank you very much once again. Accepting your answer.

Comment: @IsettyRavitejakumar I've updated my answer as you've updated your question. But there is no significant importance of it. Maybe if a line is executed tremendous amount of times you might want to check out if that line is used unnecessarily but I highly doubt it'd be a case.